# Symfony2 Eclipse Plugin CLI

Tags: eclipse, plugins, symfony, console, bundle

I'm using symfony2 plugin with Eclipse but it doesn't integrate symfony's command line instructions.

What i need is if should be possible to integrate shell symfony's command as
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml

Is there any place that describe how set these command inside eclipse as
'Run external tool'?
Should be possible to integrate inside the plugin at project level
New-> Create bundle mask?

Comment: hello, how to run symfony project in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

@ziozec: the Symfony2 plugin does not provide such a feature out of the box. However, you can indeed use the "Run external tool" Dialog to setup eclipse for running symfony commands. Simply set the path to your php executable in the "Location" field and use the project root as the working directory. In the arguments field enter "app/console